# WordPress the_title() restrict if 'Keyword'

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if there was a way in the loop to stop posts been displayed if the title of the post contains a specific keyword?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), use [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title). The difference is that the_title() outputs the title directly, while get_the_title() returns it. Hence, you can just do a simple condition:

```
if(strpos(get_the_title(), 'Keyword') === false) {
    // Title does not contain Keyword
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following at the beginning of the loop:

```
<?php if (stristr(get_the_title(),"keyword")) continue; ?>
```

Some advantages to this approach:

1. It inverts the logic so that you don't have to put your whole loop inside a condition.
2. `stristr` will match the occurence of a substring *anywhere* in the title, where strpos will not catch matches where the keyword is at the beginning of the title. Sometimes integer value 0 evaluates to false. See [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
3. `stristr` is case insensitive (use

Comment: Re 2, you should see the PHP Manual: `This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.`.

Comment: alexn's answer does work using strpos because === compares the types and can differentiate between 0 and FALSE

Comment: "Sometimes integer value 0 evaluates to false" - not in this case. (0===false) is never true

Answer (score 0):

Both answers so far are acceptable.  I prefer not to wrap chunks of code in conditionals when possible.

```
if ( preg_match('/keyword/', get_the_title() ) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a wp_title filter that could filter title content the clean way (introduced last month in 3.3 if I recall well).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title

Answer (score -1):

```
if( !preg_match( "'keyword'", get_the_title() ){
    //the loop
}
```

Using strpos is more efficient; using preg_match is more flexible as you can add regular expressions or list of words later.